# How to find unique/distinct number from list of numbers

Tags: vb.net

I have a list of numbers with anywhere from 1 to 5 digits (The numbers are values in a DataGridView column). There is only one of the numbers that is unique. All of the other numbers are duplicated at least once. I need to get the one unique number that is not duplicated.

There are many good articles on line which skirt around my task, some using linq but none look for the one only item. I found the code shown below but I don't understand what the Function(X) is.

```
Dim distinct = mynumber.DistinctBy(Function(X) X.muNumber).ToList
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a Linq query on a list of numbers and called .ToList on the query so it would result in the more friendly List(Of Integer) rather than an IEnumerable. Since you seemed sure that you only had one unique value I printed the first item of the list to the immediate window. If you were to have more unique values you could just loop through unique.

I am sure this is not the most efficient way to do this but it should work.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lstNumbers As New List(Of Integer) From {1, 5, 77, 1, 32, 5, 77}

    Dim unique = (From i In lstNumbers
                  Let ct = (From i2 In lstNumbers Where i2 = i Select i2).Count
                  Where ct = 1
                  Select i).ToList

    Debug.Print(unique(0).ToString)
End Sub
```

**EDIT** 
As per OP's comment - How to use a string of numbers.

```
    'This line won't compile unless you put quotes around it.
    Dim nums As String = "1,2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5"
    'There are a few steps to change this string into a list of numbers.
    'First get an array of strings
    Dim splitNums = nums.Split(","c) 'This overload of Split takes a Char array. The c tells it that this is a char not a string.
    'Each of the strings in the array are trimmed of any leading or trailing spaces.
    'Then the string is converted to an Integer
    'Finally the whole query is changed to a list
    Dim lstNumbers = (From i In splitNums
                      Select CInt(i.Trim)).ToList
    'and now lstNumbers is indeed a list of Integers which can be used in the code.
```

**EDIT 2**

To see if there are more than one unique numbers use a For Each loop.

```
    For Each i In unique
        TextBox1.Text &= i.ToString & ", "
    Next
```

Comment: So you have something that looks like "1, 5, 77, 1, 32, 5, 77" ? A single string with numbers in it?

Comment: I need a little more help. When I hard code numbers as you show, it works fine, however, when I insert a string variable which is a string of numbers with commas between looking exactly like the hard code numbers, I get an out of range error message.  e.g. .Dim  nums As String = 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 then insert nums into your code... Dim lstNumbers As New List(Of integer) From {num}. How do I insert the variable?

Comment: @EdJenkins See my Edit to my answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: Your edit does the job as you knew it would. Thanks. If I am not being too greedy can you get the unique numbers not knowing how many unique numbers there are? For testing purposes I added TextBox.Text = unique(0).ToString & ", " & unique(1).ToString. This works fine if there are 2 unique numbers but fails if there is only one, but if you remove the & ", " & unique(1).ToString and there are 2  unique numbers you only get the first one

Comment: @EdJenkins To answer your comment question I have added EDIT 2. If the list has only one item then your method will fail by trying to access a non-existent item. The For Each loop stops when it runs out of items.

Comment: Fantastic, you have been very helpful. Perhaps some time I can show you a demonstration video of the software that I developed using this feature. It has to do with the order of finishes of several sailboat races.

Comment: @EdJenkins Grew up watching the lightning racing on Barneget Bay NJ USA. Love the sport but haven't thought about it in years. Great app to be working on. I will keep an eye out for you on Stack Overflow.

Comment: To finish off the case where there is no unique number, I added:If TextBox1.Text = "" Then MsgBox("There are no unique numbers") End If...It works fine.

Comment: How would you change code for an array output? I now use: Dim snT As String = sn0 & sn1 & sn2
        Dim un As String = ""
        Dim splitNums = snT.Split(","c)
        Dim lstNumbers = (From i In splitNums Select (i.Trim)).ToList
        Dim unique = (From i In lstNumbers
                      Let ct = (From i2 In lstNumbers
                                Where i2 = i Select i2).Count
                      Where ct = 1 Select i).ToList
        For Each i In unique
            Dim SailNum As String = i.ToString
            un = un & SailNum & ","
        Next

Comment: To get an array change the `.ToList` to `ToArray` then unique will be an array of strings instead of a List(Of String)

Comment: You have been very helpful, thanks again. I wish I could show you the output of this app. Does Stack allow email through them.or is there another way?